# When to unregister and clear up References, Listeners & co on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks, android-lifecycle

I have a general question that now has been on my mind for a long time.
What kind of **references, variables, and listeners** should be removed in the related **Life-Cycle callbacks** (e.g. onCreate <-> onDestroy)?
A few examples:

- I have a variable `private lateinit var data: LiveData<List<String>>` which is initialized in the `onCreate` method and then fed to a recycler. Should I somehow delete it in `onDestroy`?
- I add an `OnScrollListener` to the recycler in `onCreate`, should I unregister it in `onDestroy`?

I am asking since I really don't seem to find any concise information on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an Activity 
you should remove all the references, Listeners and callback in ondestrory() 
and if you are using fragments Clear all your references, Listeners and callback in ondestroyView().

What happens when your fragment is in foreground/Activity or there is shortage of memory , GC runs and because of any references, Listeners and callback if by any chance Gc could not clean up the memory , you will get the memory leak.
So you have to make sure to remove all references, Listeners and callback in onDestory() in case of Activity and in OndestroyView in case of fragments.